# POST method is not working on same page PHP

Tags: php, post

I know this is asked question however I have tried almost steps but its not working. I know there is a silly mistake somewhere need an experts eye.
My code:

```
       // if(isset($_POST["country"])) 
       if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST")
        {
            $country = $_POST["country"];

             echo '<script language="javascript">';
                echo "alert(' Officer Already Alloted..!!!');";///Tried getting alert once POST, but no message
                echo '</script>';
        }
            //? $country = $_POST["country"] : $company=1;

    ?>
        <form action="#" method="POST">
        <select class="country" name="wcpbc-manual-country" id="country" >
         <?
            $list=mysqli_query($con,"select * from country where status!='False'");
        while($row_list=mysqli_fetch_assoc($list)){
            $display="+".$row_list['phonecode']."-".$row_list['name'];
            $flag=$row_list['isosmall'];

            ?>
 <!--<select class="country" name="wcpbc-manual-country" id="country">-->

    <option value="<?$row_list['phonecode']?>" data-iconurl="https://ipdata.co/flags/<?php echo $flag; ?>.png" <?php if($country==$row_list['name']){echo "selected";} ?>><? echo $display;?></option>
    <!--<option value="IN" data-iconurl="https://ipdata.co/flags/in.png">IN some text</option>-->
    <?
        }
        ?>
    </select>
    </form>

    <script type="text/javascript">
$("#country").selectBoxIt();
</script>
```

Actually I am trying to get selected value on to dropdown, it seems POST is not working for assigning value to `$country` variable
I tried:
1. `if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST")` 
2. used `form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>"`

 Please help.Thanks

Comment: `select`'s name is `wcpbc-manual-country`. And a `#` in `action` attribute of form tag?

Comment: how about **submitting** the form?

Comment: `#` in the action means it will post to itself @vivek_23

Comment: @JayBlanchard Didn't knew that and yes it basically appends it to the URL after submitting, but is kinda redundant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `<option />` values are empty:

```
<?$row_list['phonecode']?>
```

Should be

```
<?php echo $row_list['phonecode']; ?>
```

or at least

```
<?= $row_list['phonecode']; ?>
```

Also as mentioned by Always Sunny you are not visibly **submitting** the form. We don't know if there is Javascript going on but there must be some kind of submit action. I think you checked that in the browsers developer console.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I knew there was some silly mistake. just added `=` like `<?= $row_list['phonecode']; ?>` and it worked

Answer (score 0):

you should use

```
 <select class="country" name="country" id="country" >

     <option value="<?php echo $row_list['phonecode']?>" data-iconurl="https://ipdata.co/flags/<?php echo $flag; ?>.png" <?php if($country==$row_list['name']){echo "selected";} ?>><? echo $display;?></option>
```

Comment: What should the OP "use" your code? A ***good answer*** will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done in such a manner, not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO.

Comment: @JayBlanchard i was just pointing out where it needs to be corrected .sorry if its not clear